# a simple application for calling a web service using backbone collection and display it

Tags: json, backbone.js, collections

I am new to backbone.js library. As an exercise, I want to call my web service to fetch some JSON data. Here is my code:

```
$(function(){

$('#okbtn').on('click', function(){
    Server=Backbone.Model.extend({});

    ServerList= Backbone.Collection.extend(
            {
                model:Server,
                url:"/LoginWebService/Domain1?DomainName=mail",
                initialize:function(){alert('In collection init');},
                parse:{
                    success:function(response){alert(response);},

                    error:function(){alert("error");}
                }
            }
    );

    list=new ServerList;
    list.fetch();
    console.log(list.length);
});
```

});

This gives error in `Backbone.js` as

> Uncaught TypeError: Property 'parse' of object [object Object] is not
>   a function

Although, the network tab in console shows the object returned from the web service.

Why this error is coming and how can I show a response from a server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parse` doesn't handle `success` and `error` callbacks, at least as far as I know (here are the docs for `parse`: http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-parse. `success` and `error` are options in `fetch`, so just move the `success` and `error` callbacks to `fetch` and get rid of `parse`. So try changing your code from this

```
ServerList= Backbone.Collection.extend(
        {
            model:Server,
            url:"/LoginWebService/Domain1?DomainName=mail",
            initialize:function(){alert('In collection init');},
            parse:{
                success:function(response){alert(response);},

                error:function(){alert("error");}
            }
        }
);

list=new ServerList;
list.fetch();
```

to this

```
ServerList= Backbone.Collection.extend(
        {
            model:Server,
            url:"/LoginWebService/Domain1?DomainName=mail",
            initialize:function(){alert('In collection init');}
        }
);

list=new ServerList;
list.fetch({
    success:function(collection, response){alert(response);},

    error:function(){alert("error");}
});
```

Docs for `fetch`: http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch

Comment: Thannks that worked! It prints [object Object] in the alert as my JSON object is complex. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad it helped! Actually, the alert was giving you the `collection`, not the `response`, because the collection is the first argument passed to the callback and response is the second. It won't really make much of a difference, but I fixed my answer to make that more clear.

Comment: can you tell me how can I see the response which is getting back from the server?

Comment: @user3151543, one way of seeing the response would be to use the code that I provided, and inside the `success` callback add `console.log(response)`. If you are testing it out the browser, just check the console in the developer tools, and it should provide you with the response object. If you are using Chrome, open the DevTools and go to the `Network` tab before you execute the `fetch`. The response will be the new file that is added to the end of the list of files.